# Disable users from valid list

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I've got a list of valid users provided by HR. The formatting was not cool, so I managed to get a new file like I wanted: one column, on each line the samaccountname (1st letter of firstname and name).

My file looks like this:

```
bgates
sjobs
bmarley
epresley
etc.
```

I'd like to disable users who are NOT in this list. I guess I have to deal with some `if` stuff, but I don't know how to.

@HariHaran, i have tried this:

```
      #this part works fine
        $list = Import-Csv .\listadnames2.csv -Delimiter ";"

        $lol =

        ForEach ($user in $list)
        {

         $user.prenom[0] + $user.nom 

        }  

        $lol | Out-File .\samaccountnames.csv 

        $validusers = Import-Csv .\samaccountnames.csv
        $fullusers = Get-ADUser -Filter * -SearchBase "OU=USERS,DC=domain,DC=com" -ResultPageSize 0 -Prop samaccountname | Select samaccountname

        foreach ($u in $validusers)

        if ($u -match $fullusers) {continue} else 

        {
        Set-ADUser -Identity $($._) -Enabled $false -whatif
        }
```

Comment: What have you tried ?

Comment: if you load the list into a $Var you can use the `-in` or the `-contains` array operators to see if an item is in a collection. so, grab the full user list, iterate thru it, do a `$CurUser -in $ValidUserList`, and deal with the ones that come up false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The users list (samaccountnames.csv) you create in `$lol` is not a CSV file, but simply a text file with all constructed usernames each on a separate line.
Therefore you should read the file using 
`$validusers = Get-Content .\samaccountnames.csv` instead of `$validusers = Import-Csv .\samaccountnames.csv`.
Then you'll have an array of samaccountnames to work with.

Next, I wonder why you use `-ResultPageSize 0`.. The default setting is 256 objects per page, so I can only imaging you could need this value to be higher than this default, not less.
(see [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/addsadministration/get-aduser?view=win10-ps))

Taken from the part where you read the samaccountnames file, I think this will do the job:

```
$validusers = Get-Content .\samaccountnames.csv
# property 'SamAccountName' is returned by default as are 
# 'DistinguishedName', 'Enabled', 'GivenName', 'Name', 'ObjectClass', 'ObjectGUID', 'SID', 'Surname' and 'UserPrincipalName'

# get the user objects from AD and loop through them to see if they need to be set disabled
Get-ADUser -Filter * -SearchBase "OU=USERS,DC=domain,DC=com" | ForEach-Object {
    # the $_ automatic variable now holds an AD user object

    # or use if($_.SamAccountName -notin $validusers). Only for PowerShell version 3.0 and up
    if ($validusers -notcontains $_.SamAccountName) {  
        $_ | Set-ADUser -Enabled $false -WhatIf
    }
}
```

Comment: @Fab Sorry, my first post used `-in` and `-contains`. My bad.. This should have been `-notin` and `-notcontains` of course. I have edited the answer.